# enable Local git repo for azure webapp using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

Hi trying to publish code using FTP which is timecomsuming. Wanted to use local git repo. how can i enable local git repo using ARM cmdkets like new-azurermresource.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following PowerShell Commands to enable local git repo for your Web app. (I am using Azure PowerShell 1.6.0)

```
$a = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceId /subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourcegroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<web app name>/Config/web -ApiVersion 2015-08-01

$a.Properties.scmType = "LocalGit"

Set-AzureRmResource -PropertyObject $a.Properties -ResourceId /subscriptions/<subscription id>/resourcegroups/<resource group name>/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/<web app name>/Config/web -ApiVersion 2015-08-01
```

The credential for the git repo is the same as the FTP's. And, the git repo URL is `https://<FTP user name>@<web app name>.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/<web app name>.git`

Comment: thanks jack ..

am facing prob now while pushing code ...

fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://ServiceAccount@copycode12.scm.azure websites.net:443/copycode12.git/'

can you let me know what cred to pass and how ...

shareeditundeleteflag

Comment: The credential is the same as the FTP's, if you have ever set it through the portal. If no, you can set it through [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com). **App Service** -> **<your app>** -> **Deployment Credential** under "App Deployment" -> Enter your username, password, and then click **Save**.

Comment: Yeah i have set it from portal and able to deploy for one app .. now i have more than one webapps.. i need to push code to all of these using same username without recreating[assuming one username created can be used for all webapps under the same subscription]. username and pwd.. am saved using cred manager username and pwd while pushing to first but while pushing to second webapp it is again prompting for cred.. how can i suppress?? in  short i would like to save single username and pwd and deploy to all webapps ???

Comment: i can enable github also as local git just by replacing localgit with github for scmtype ?

Comment: That's quite a different question. You can create a new question and describe it in detail. GitHub Repo for Azure web apps is involved with entering credential in Azure portal, and setting Repo URL. It's difficult to answer in a comment.